# Excel VBA Loop: Copy IDs in a list, Paste, Print PDF for each

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I need to generate a PDF for each ID listed in column AQ. I am trying to write a code that:

1. Copies the first ID number
2. Pastes it into the input cell of the report template
3. Saves the sheet as a pdf
4. Repeats this for the next ID number, and so on until the column is empty.

This is the code I have so far

```
Sub GeneratePDF()

Dim r As Range, cell As Range
Set r = Range(Range("AQ1"), Range("AQ1").End(xlDown))

For Each cell In r

Sheets("Specialist Roster").Select
Range("H2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Weekly Productivity").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

ManagerName = Range("O5").Value
SpecialistName = Range("Q1").Value
Folder = Range("Q2").Value

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Users\sdevereueawax\Desktop\Weekly Productivity Reports\" & ManagerName & "\" & SpecialistName & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't seem to be copying anything from column AQ?

Comment: `For Each cell In r` ...cell never used after that..and there is no `next` to close that `for each`

Comment: Any suggestions on how to copy the ID numbers in column AQ and paste them into H1 (the input cell used to perform all the vlookups)?